# CSURF not working if the Session cookie is secure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, cookies, express-session

I am stumped as to when I set the cookie to secure, the csrf of node is not working.

```
//Load Cooike Parser
app.use(cookieParser(secret));
//Load Session Store
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret:secret,
    cookie:{
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day,
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true
    },
    store: sessionStore
}));
//Load POST data parser
//Form sent should be in JSON format
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Initiate CSRF on middleware
//set the CSRF cookie Header
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN',req.csrfToken());
    next();
});
```

This setup is using MongoDB for storing the session data. Reading on the `express-session` docs, I come across to this ...

> Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. **However, it requires an https-enabled website**, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set. If you have your node.js behind a proxy and are using secure: true, you need to set "trust proxy" in express:

*Source:* [npm express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

I'm currently running the site locally, so it's not HTTPS. I would like to know is how does `secure:true` relate to the not passing the csrf test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the provided code sample does not cover the creation of the form I will assume that you correctly include the `_csrf` value. Or that you set the corresponding header with JavaScript.

**Let's start by explaining why you shouldn't be doing `res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN',req.csrfToken());`.**

The default way that `csurf` module works is it generates or returns the `_csrf` token when you run `req.csrfToken()`, but it also saves this token in the session.

If you want to use cookie instead of the session as the storage method you should be passing `cookie: true` or `cookie: cookieOptions` as the initialisation value to `csurf` instead of manually setting the cookie.

This is relevant because if you don't use the intended option parameter the `csurf` will try to look up the token value for verification from the session object, which means your cookie setting is useless.

**Now as for the part why it fails on HTTPS.**

When you set `secure: true` what it does is send cookies from the server to the browser with the `secure` flag.

As per the [OWASP page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag):

> The secure flag is an option that can be set by the application server when sending a new cookie to the user within an HTTP Response. The purpose of the secure flag is to prevent cookies from being observed by unauthorized parties due to the transmission of a the cookie in clear text.
>
> To accomplish this goal, browsers which support the secure flag **will only send** cookies with the secure flag when the request is going to a **HTTPS page**. Said in another way, the browser **will not send** a cookie with the secure flag set over an unencrypted **HTTP request**.

This includes the session token cookie, which is used to look up information in the sessionStore.

So the browser does not send a session cookie to the server. The server creates a new empty session and because we are back to the default `csurf` operating method it will try to look up a token from an empty session. There will not be a token so the comparison will fail.

As a side note this also means that your session in general fail.

NB! As a side note if you are more interested I suggest you read the [OWASP CSRF mitigation cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Or my book about [Node.js Web Application Security](https://secureyournodejs.com), which among other things covers the CSRF and various mitigation methods implemented with Node.js.

Comment: From what I understand, since I am using a different session storage (using MongoDB for session), I shouldn't bother setting the cookie properties in the session init. it only confuses the the code?

Comment: It confuses the code and also since you are not using the proper cookie settings the csurf library will not take that into account.